# What is meant by a full abstract model of a lambda-calculus like language?

Tags: lambda-calculus, semantics, types-and-programming-languages

> The simply typed lambda-calculus with numbers and fix has long been a favorite experimental subject for programming language researchers, since it is the simplest language in which a range of subtle semantic phenomena such as full abstraction arise.

I tried to find a definition for full-abstract model but I haven't found such. This quote is from Pierce's TAPL book. Note that there is also a related question: [What is a "model" of lambda calculus?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/104192/what-is-a-model-of-lambda-calculus) on the site that has not been answered.

Comment: Full abstraction is used in when you are working in denotational semantics for a programming language. A model is fully abstract when semantic equivalence implies contextual equivalence. I think it was introduced by Milner https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397577900536

Comment: the answer to this can be found in a series of lectures in Winter School on Denotational Semantics (30 Jan - 3 Feb, 2017)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In denotational semantics, you want to be able to map each of your language terms to some object in your semantic domain or model. Now, it cannot be any arbitrary domain/model as you like, but, informally speaking, something that gives a good intuition about how the language works (its computational behavior).

[Milner](http://sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397577900536) tried to formalize what this "intuition" should be and called it full abstraction. Formally, a model is fully abstract if all observationally equivalent terms in the object language represent the same object in the model. Equationally:
$$\text{if }  ⟦t_1⟧ = ⟦t_2⟧  \text{then } t_1 \rightsquigarrow t_2 $$
where $\rightsquigarrow$ represents observational equivalence. In case of lambda-calculus observational equivalence would be $\beta\eta\alpha$ conversions and $⟦\_⟧$ is the denotation function.

There are few papers that you might want to take a look at if you are interested in seeing some full abstract models of lambda like languages:

1. [Plotkin's](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397577900445) paper that gives a full abstract model of the lambda like language called LCF
2. [Mulmuley's](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/715926) paper gives a full abstract model of typed lambda calculus.
3. [Hyland and Ong's](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540100929171) papers give a full abstract model of PCF using game semantics

Comment: Surely the equation you wrote is simply the soundness of the model, full abstraction should go in the other direction no?

Comment: @cody indeed. fixed it now.